# Calculating modularity gain of switching a node from one community to another (Louvain algorithm)

Tags: clustering, references, graph-theory, networks

I am trying to implement the Louvain algorithm in PySpark.

An important part of the algorithm involves calculating the modularity gain of taking node $i$ out of its current community $C_0$ and placing it in a neighboring community $C_1$.

On page four of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476.pdf), the authors describe the modularity gain as a two-step process:

1. Calculating the modularity gain of removing $i$ from its current community; and
2. Calculating the modularity gain of placing isolated node $i$ to the new community.

The second step is described in equation 2 (page 4), but the first step is only addressed as:

> *A similar expression is used in order to evaluate the change of modularity when i is removed from its community.*

I have been unable to find the expression for the first step.

Does anyone know how to compute the modularity gain of removing node $i$ from its current community? Could you please share where you found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the author (Renaud Lambiotte) and he shared the answer with me.

The change in modularity of removing node $x$ from its community $C_x$ is:
$$\triangle Q_{remove} = - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i \in C_x \setminus \{x\}} \Big[ A_{ix} - \frac{k_i k_x}{2m} \Big] $$

The change in modularity of inserting node $x$, which is now alone in its community, into $C_1$ is:

$$ \triangle Q_{insert} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i \in C_1} \big[ A_{ix} - \frac{k_i k_x}{2m} \Big]$$

Where $A_{ix}$ is the weight of the edge between vertices $i$ and $x$, $m = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}$, and $k_i$ and $k_x$ are the degrees of vertices $i$ and $x$ respectively.

Comment: This result and its derivation are detailed here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154224/the-modularity-difference-in-louvain-algorithm-for-community-detection-in-graphs